# What is the element query in Mongodb to get value?

Tags: mongodb, collections

I am working on mongodb Aggregation query but i don't know how to get the array value from the JSON by joining two collection, please go through my below sample JSON.

```
COKE Collection

[{
   "name": "Mirinda",
   "_id": "894567894769476948"
 }, {
   "name": "COKE",
   "_id": "857856856879694769"
 }, {
   "name": "PEPSI",
   "_id": "785485686846684684"
}]

COKE Order Collection

{
   "_id": "0908080808031338013101",
   "drink": [{
       "name": "Mirinda",
       "_id": "894567894769476948"
   }, {
       "name": "COKE",
       "_id": "857856856879694769"
   }, {
       "name": "PEPSI",
       "_id": "785485686846684684"
   }]
}

Expected OutPut:

Miranda name and _id should come of Orders collection by passing _id.
```

Above sample son i want to get the name value by joining the collections _id, please kindly go through my post and let me know if you have any suggestion.

Comment: please add the expected output, I'm not sure to understand what you want

Comment: hey i have updated my post please check and let me know

Comment: which id are you passing? you are already storing name in both collections. what is the query that you are trying?

Comment: hey suppose if i'll do db.COKE collection by joining COKEODER collection then i should get that particular drinks name